# Codeigniter - Get_where base from session_userdata

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I want to select all the rows that emp id's are match to my session userdata (emp_id).  Here's my code. I get so many errors and no row has been selected. Someone help me please. Thanks

Model:

```
public function get_save_samp($emp_id) {
   $query = $this->db->get_where('tblsavesample', array('emp_id' => 
       $emp_id));
   return $query->row_array();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function show() {

    $emp_id = $this->session->userdata('emp_id');
    $data['save'] = $this->user_model->get_save_samp($emp_id);
    $this->load->view('show',$data);
}
```

Views:

```
<?php foreach ($save as $row) { ?>                                                                                      
    <td style="width: " ><?php echo $row->emp_id ?></td>
    <td style="width: " ><?php echo $row->emp_code?></td>
    <td style="width: " ><?php echo $row->emp_name ?></td>
<?php   }>
```

Comment: Only one issue is there use `result` instead of `row_array`

Comment: <td style="width: " ><?php echo $row->emp_code ?></td>
there is no semicolon

Comment: @RahulMeshram no issue with semicolon when single line statement enclosed in `<?php ?>`

Comment: Oh, that's new to me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
public function get_save_samp($emp_id) {
       $query = $this->db->get_where('tblsavesample', array('emp_id' => 
       $emp_id));
        return $query->result();
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try solution for your problem :

Changes your modal function :

> Modal.php

```
public function get_save_samp($emp_id) {
     $this->db->select("*"); 
     $this->db->where('id', $emp_id);
     $this->db->get('tblsavesample');
     return $query->row();
}
```

> Views:

```
<?php foreach ($save as $row) {?>
   <td style="width: " ><?php echo $row->emp_id ?></td>
   <td style="width: " ><?php echo $row->emp_code ?></td>
   <td style="width: " ><?php echo $row->emp_name ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort sir. Errors are gone but still has no output. Nothing is listed or selected in my views table.

Comment: Please first check your object return value or not. `$save`

Answer (score 0):

Change your Modal Code like this :

```
  public function get_save_samp($emp_id) {
     //$query = $this->db->get_where('tblsavesample', array('emp_id' =>$emp_id));
     $this->db->select("*"); 
     $this->db->where_in('id', $emp_id);
     $query = $this->db->get('tblsavesample');
     return $query->result();
  }
```

And Change your Controller code like this to check what data are we getting inside controller.

```
public function show()
{    
    $emp_id       = $this->session->userdata('emp_id');
    $data['save'] = $this->user_model->get_save_samp($emp_id);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_R($data['save']);
    exit();
    $this->load->view('show', $data);
}
```

Comment: Here I am Assuming you will be getting an array for `$emp_id`.

Comment: Yes you're right sir. But unfortunately when I use your code to my Modal, it has no output in my views. Nothing is listed or selected.

Comment: OKey then let's go step by step..After implementing my code do you get the data inside Controller?

Comment: How can i know that sir? My code for controller is this one...

public function show()
{

    $emp_id       = $this->session->userdata('emp_id');
    $data['save'] = $this->user_model->get_save_samp($emp_id);
    $this->load->view('show', $data);
}

Answer (score 0):

row_array() returns the first row only. If you want all the records to be returned, use result_array() instead.

```
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Link : [click](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

Answer (score 0):

row_array() used to return only single record. change your code in model as follows :

```
public function get_save_samp($emp_id) {  

$query = $this->db->get_where('tblsavesample', array('emp_id' => 
   $emp_id));

return $query->result_array();

}
```

and check number of records returned in your controller as follows:

```
$data['save'] = $this->user_model->get_save_samp($emp_id);
echo $data['save']->num_rows();
```

if this displays 0, then you have no matching records in your database table.

to test the query, try to execute the same query in mysql